# polars filter condition column name and col

Tags: python, python-polars

I found that only "=" condition, column name is OK,
But why are other conditions denied,  and make name error?

polars version 0.20.5

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "foo": [1, 2, 3`enter code here`],
        "bar": [6, 7, 8],
        "ham": ["a", "b", "c"],
    }
)
print(df.filter(pl.col("foo") > 1))
print(df.filter(foo = 1))
```

Above polars codes are OK. But without "=" condition, denied. Sample code:

```
print(df.filter(foo>1))
# NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

I like simple code. So, columns name is useful.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so that's one is actually interesting. Note that you didn't use equality operator (`==`) in your second statement, which wouldn't have worked:

```
df.filter(foo == 1)

NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

You've used assignment (`=`) operator, and the statement works because [`filter()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.filter.html) also implements [`**kwargs`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) syntax. So what essentially is happening is `foo=1` is parsed as `name` = `value` parameters.
For example this would also work:

```
print(df.filter(foo=1, bar=6))

shape: (1, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ foo ┆ bar ┆ ham │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ str │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 6   ┆ a   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

using [`pl.col()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/col.html) within filter works cause it returns `Expr` which is one of the implemented signatures of `filter()` method:

```
print(df.filter(pl.col('foo') == 1))

shape: (1, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ foo ┆ bar ┆ ham │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ str │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 6   ┆ a   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```